# Need Regex to be Non-Greedy

Tags: regex

Question:  How do I get a regex wildcard to select only between the two nearest elements instead of going on to further similar elements?  
I have a VERY long list of names that need to have the last name separated from the rest by a tab character.  In order to accomplish this, I've inserted a placeholder character (#) just before the return of each line, and replaced all spaces in the names with a different placeholder character (@) for my regex to reference.  These names are all first, middle initial, then last, having a space on each side of the middle initial.  So, with my placeholder characters inserted, the list looks like this (short sample):  
Edward@C.@Sellner# 
James@J.@Megivern# 
J.@Philip@Newell# 
 
I need to isolate only the last name between the @ and # placeholders.  When I try and do that, my regex is going to the first @ placeholder, instead of stopping at the second @ placeholder, just before the last name.  Here's what I'm using in my search: 
@([\s\S]*?)# 
which I would replace with: 
(tab)$1# 
after which I would convert all placeholders back to their original state. 
What should I be doing differently here? 
 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
@([^@#]*)#
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RcDtrG/1)

**Details**

- `@` - a `@` char
- `([^@#]*)` - Group 1: 0 or more chars other than `@` and `#`
- `#` - a `#` char.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%40(%5B%5E%40%23%5D*)%23):

[image]